# Zod, Using Type Generics to Build A Schema

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, zod

I'm trying to follow the [documentation](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#writing-generic-functions) for using type generics with zod. I'd like to have a function that takes in a zod scheam and produces a zod schema such as this.

```js
export function createResponseSchema<R extends z.ZodTypeAny>(
  resourceSchema: R
) {
  return z.object({
    result: resourceSchema,
    code: z.string(),
    message: z.string(),
  });
}

export function useResponseSchema<R extends z.ZodTypeAny>(resourceSchema: R) {
  return createResponseSchema(resourceSchema).parse({
    code: '200',
    message: 'OK',
    result: [{test: 'test'}],
  }).result;
//    ^? Error
}
```

However when doing so TS is freaking out aobut result not being a property...

```
Property 'result' does not exist on type '{ [k in keyof baseObjectOutputType<{ result: R; code: ZodString; message: ZodString; }>]: baseObjectOutputType<{ result: R; code: ZodString; message: ZodString; }>[k]; }'.ts(2339)
```

The odd bit is it works fine if I do add `.array()` like this..

```js
export function useResponseSchema<R extends z.ZodTypeAny>(resourceSchema: R) {
  return createResponseSchema(resourceSchema.array()).parse({
    code: '200',
    message: 'OK',
    result: [{test: 'test'}],
  }).result;
//    ^? NO ERROR?!
}
```

but I don't want to make it an array. I don't understand why this would make it work.

tsconfig.json if it's important..

```json
{
  "extends": "./node_modules/gts/tsconfig-google.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "build",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "test/**/*.ts"],
  "ts-node": {
    "transpileOnly": true,
    "files": true,
    "experimentalResolver": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Your first snippet declares `createResponseSchema` and then uses `createSearchResponseSchema`, which is a different variable. Is that a typo? If I fix that, I [don't see a problem](https://tsplay.dev/WJAE5m)

Comment: Edit - fixed the typo. That was due to trying to simplify the example.. Fixing that in my editor still fails.. Maybe it's tied to my compiler settings or version of zod?

Comment: It was the zod version. Thankyou @AlexWayne for the sanity check. Let this be a lesson. If you know something should work.. try it in typescript playground!